# SVD for low rank matrices

Tags: python, numpy, svd

Does anyone know how to do svd for low-ranked matrices in python? I could not find any built in function, should I write the code myself? I am doing sad on a 80*50 matrix with rank 10, so numpy svd does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((80,50))
matrix[:10,:10] = np.eye(10)

np.linalg.svd(matrix)
```

[Reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch has a special [low rank SVD implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.svd_lowrank.html)